# WebClientPrint for client-side printing javascript issue on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, printing

I recently started using  [WebClientPrint](http://www.neodynamic.com/Products/Help/WebClientPrint2.0/index.html) to handle our client side printing needs.

We need to print 2 copies of a document so I run the javascript printing function twice

```
>jsWebClientPrint.print('printerName=' + $('#installedPrinterName').val());
>jsWebClientPrint.print('printerName=' + $('#installedPrinterName').val());
```

On IE and Firefox this has the desired effect and prints the document twice.
On Chrome it has an odd behavior, the first time it prints the document, and on the second its does nothing...
No error and no warning. When I try to debug I can clearly see the two instruction being called but only the first one works.

Any idea of what is different about Chrome handling JS that might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not add it to the list like this

```
cpj.PrintFileGroup.Add(New PrintFile(context.Server.MapPath("~/files/file.doc"), "file.doc"))
24.
'DispatchForm.xls PRINT TO Printer2
25.
cpj.PrintFileGroup.Add(New PrintFile(context.Server.MapPath("~/files/file.doc"), "file.doc"))
```

and then print it out with one print out

```
jsWebClientPrint.print();
```